# Disable JIT debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, jit, process.start

This topic has been asked and answered in many questions and I did my due diligence but I just can't figure out why I am having the issue I have.

**In testfailure.exe:**

```
namespace testfailture
{
 class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
  {
       try
      {
          throw new Exception("I want to report this in the parent window");
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          throw ex;
      }
   }
}
```

**In test.exe:**

```
internal void Execute(string packageVersion)
 {

    Process exeProcess = new Process();   
    exeProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "testfailure.exe";
    exeProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    exeProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    exeProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    try
    {
        exeProcess.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(exeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

When I run the program, I get the pop-up and wouldn't let the program proceed until an action is taken.

[image]

I thought this was due to JIT debugging so I did everything from: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a52eb0ae-bcd8-4043-9661-d5fc3aa5167c/getting-rid-of-justintime-debugger?forum=vsdebug

That is one problem I have but ultimate what I want to do is subprocess reporting back the error (not console.writeline because I want to use that for reporting status) to the parent and display in parent's window.

Any thoughts?

By the way, I am using Visual Studio Professional 2012. Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit #1----------------------------

My process fully expects everything to work but what I am trying to do is to code for unexpected failures. When fails, I want to have a good dialogue so I can easily and quickly detect and debug.

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger, fix your code instead.  Exceptions cannot bridge a process boundary, your program is supposed to crash like this.  You'll need to re-think your strategy, this cannot work.

Comment: Yes, I agree. My process fully expects everything to work but I am coding for unexpected  failure. When that happens, what I am doing will help me detect and debug quickly.

Comment: Also, don't do `throw ex;` unless you want to reset the call stack of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throwing an unhandled exception cannot be passed to a parent process.

What you CAN do, however, is to write data to StandardError, and capture that in the parent process.

The example below is from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y49kb86(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
    Public Sub Main()
      Dim args() As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
      Dim errorOutput As String = "" 
      ' Make sure that there is at least one command line argument. 
      If args.Length <= 1 Then
         errorOutput += "You must include a filename on the command line." +
                        vbCrLf
      End If 

      For ctr As Integer = 1 To args.GetUpperBound(0)
         ' Check whether the file exists. 
         If Not File.Exists(args(ctr)) Then
            errorOutput += String.Format("'{0}' does not exist.{1}",
                                         args(ctr), vbCrLf)
         Else 
            ' Display the contents of the file. 
            Dim sr As New StreamReader(args(ctr))
            Dim contents As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
            sr.Close()
            Console.WriteLine("***** Contents of file '{0}':{1}{1}",
                              args(ctr), vbCrLf)
            Console.WriteLine(contents)
            Console.WriteLine("*****{0}", vbCrLf)
         End If 
      Next 

      ' Check for error conditions. 
      If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorOutput) Then 
         ' Write error information to a file.
         Console.SetError(New StreamWriter(".\ViewTextFile.Err.txt"))
         Console.Error.WriteLine(errorOutput)
         Console.Error.Close()
         ' Reacquire the standard error stream. 
         Dim standardError As New StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardError())
         standardError.AutoFlush = True
         Console.SetError(standardError)
         Console.Error.WriteLine("{0}Error information written to ViewTextFile.Err.txt",
                                 vbCrLf)
      End If 
   End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! I should have researched more on console. Thank you!